# why do I need to use strtotime() to convert mySQL time to PHP time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column of a type "time" in mySQL database. I am displaying it in a 12 hour format on a website. Why do I need to use strtotime()?

```
$time = date('g:i a', strtotime( $time)) ;
```

I know that it works, I am just wondering why I need to use a special function to convert one type of "time" into another. Does PHP consider mySQL time column type a string?

Comment: Simple answer, YES. However it is better to do the formating in the query itself using the format function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @DavidSoussan if you can. A lot of times you'd have to `SELECT` each column (e.g. `SELECT start_time, end_time`) instead of being able to use `SELECT *`. Formatting in the query is oftentimes not feasible in cases where you have a lot of columns you're selecting.

Comment: So then use a VIEW which lists all the columns and formats the dates etc. Write it once use it many.Many purists would say that SELECT * is an abomination. I don't, but then I don't shirk from listing the columns when I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `date()` function accepts an integer timestamp, which denotes the number of seconds sinds [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). In your database, the time is stored differently (a date string, which PHP just sees as a normal string), so you need to convert it first. So, your assumptions are right.